# Why was Dumbledore sneaking into the girls' dorm?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction, hp-methods-of-rationality

After reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171736/75000) and the comments associated with it, I'm curious as to what Albus' reasons were for sneaking into Lily's bedroom while she slept.

**So why'd he do it?**

Comment: [Relevant comic?](http://floccinaucinihilipilificationa.tumblr.com/image/162907143262)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is addressed in [chapter 119](http://www.hpmor.com/chapter/119). Dumbledore's long-term goal was to prevent the world from being destroyed. Since he knows the general circumstances that will cause the apocalypse, he's using *other prophecies* to prevent that from happening.

> *There were no prophecies of how the world might be saved, so I found
>   the prophecies that offered loopholes in the destruction; and I
>   brought about the strange and complex conditions for those prophecies
>   to come to pass. I ensured that Voldemort discovered a certain one of
>   those prophecies, and so (even as I had feared) condemned your parents
>   to death and made you what you are. **I wrote a strange hint in your
>   mother's Potions textbook, having no idea why I must;** and this proved
>   to show Lily how to help her sister, and ensured you would gain
>   Petunia Evans's heartfelt love. I snuck invisibly into your bedroom in
>   Oxford and administered the potion that is given to students with
>   Time-Turners, to extend your day's cycle by two hours. When you were
>   six years old I smashed a rock that was on your windowsill, and to
>   this day I cannot imagine why.*

Comment: I wonder if that story would hold up with the police

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - If the latest reports are true, he won't be able to show the next Fantastic Beasts film as evidence that he's not into that sort of thing

Comment: @Valorum - Hmmm?

Comment: @Adamant - http://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/2018/02/01/harry-potter-fans-slam-cowardly-decision-ignore-dumbledores/

Comment: @valorum it always strikes me as odd when "interested in men" is equated with "not interested in women." Bisexual people exist...

Comment: @StephenCollings - Which is true, except that Dumbledore isn't bisexual, he's gay.

Comment: @Valorum - It's true, it would be very odd for Dumbledore to confront Grindelwald without acknowledging what they shared. What's odd is that I heard rumors that Dumbledore would have a (non-Grindelwald) boyfriend in this one...what happened to that?

Comment: @Adamant - I suspect it's because they realised that if one of the iconic characters is shown to be openly gay, the film will almost certainly be denied a release in China (costing them around $85M) and that the box office take in other markets will be lowered. Is it worth $150m to WB to give Dumbledore a boyfriend just to please a small number of western fans? Evidently not.

Comment: @Valorum - Well, that's the cynical way of looking at it, certainly. Pffft. Prejudice over artistic integrity any day, I suppose. Anyway, it's not as if there aren't plenty of openly gay characters in film - not enough, maybe, but certainly a company can't pretend that it's financially impossible.

Comment: @Adamant - If you can guarantee that 16.7M additional people will go see this film if they make him gay, then you can have (openly) gay Dumbledore. Because I can guarantee that if they *do*, then 16.6M won't go and see it in China.

Comment: @Valorum - If they really want to make even *more* money at the expense of realism and ethics, why not just remove the scenes with Dumbledore's boyfriend in the China cut? Studios have done that before. That way you get everyone.

Comment: @Adamant - That doesn't work. The Chinese get grumpy if there are overseas cuts.

Comment: @Valorum - There have *totally* been censored film versions for China before.